# Como passar dados para todas as views num padrão MVC?

Tags: php, mvc

Estou construindo uma pequena aplicação MVC com `PHP`, seguinte estrutura de diretórios:

- controllers/ (Arquivos dos controladores)
- views/ (Arquivos de views)

Em cada controlador, eu passo uma instância do Objeto **VIEW** com um array com dados para poder usa-lo no arquivo da view, *exemplo:*

```
New View('Busca','header', 'footer', $viewParams );
```

Obs: esses 2 parâmetros que passei (header e footer), serão incluídos juntos da view, *exemplo:*

```
Include Header;    
Include Busca ( **a view que passei por parâmetro** );    
Include Footer;
```

Até ai tudo bem, posso passar os dados para qualquer view, a partir de seu controlador, mas como eu fatiei meu site com HEADER e FOOTER , e esses arquivos não estão na regra da minha view que é pegar os arquivos de VIEW por pastas, exemplo:

**Estrutura do Diretório**

```
Views/Busca/    
     - Index.phtml

Views/Error/    
     - Index.phtml

Como HEADER e FOOTER, estão em:    
     - Views/Header.phtml    
     - Views/Footer.phtml
```

Só que preciso alterar valores dinâmicamente na minha header, o único modo de fazer isso é em todo Controlador, colocar o mesmo código e passar por parâmetro para minha view, *exemplo*:

```
BuscaAction()
{    
    $setParams = array('title_page' => 'Título do Site');
    $view = New view('Busca','header','footer',$setParams);    
    $view->render();    
}
```

---

```
ErrorAction(){    
    $setParams = array('title_page' => 'Título do Site');    
    $view = New view('Error','header','footer',$setParams);    
    $view->render();    
}
```

Em vez disso, gostaria de passar essas informação de forma única e que possa alterar dinâmicamente, como se fosse um controlador normal, passar pelo construtor do controller é uma solução?

Answer (score 1):

Boas, o problema que apresentas parece-me fácil de resolver, os controladores em que precises de definir um header e um footer basta hardarem de um controlador que tenha esses dados.

exemplo:

```
<?php

class BaseController {
    protected $data = [ 
        'header' => 'views/header.php',
        'footer' => 'views/footer.php'
    ];

    function __construct() { }
}

class HomeController extends BaseController {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        var_dump($this->data);
    }

}

new Homecontroller();
```

outputs:

```
array(2) {
  'header' =>
  string(16) "views/header.php"
  'footer' =>
  string(16) "views/footer.php"
}
```

No entanto podes usar a minha framework http://pedrosimoes79.github.io/silverbullet/, para fazeres o que queres, basta criar uma triade MVC que trate do header e do footer e outros pormenores de layout, e depois chamar o controlador/acção na view, sem precisar de obter dados no controlador principal, ie, tudo muito bem separadinho ;)